# 32k Transaction Size, 0.0005 Fees. Will it ever be confirmed?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

https://blockchain.info/tx/779afbdbdb03d13743626c8b1028404a6b16e65a2373ab5f744d206f34996c9a?show_adv=true

I made this TX from okcoin with 0.0005 (default) fees.
After 1 day it finally showed up in the blockchain, now after 48h i see no confirmation. The Transaction size seems really high, compared to the
average of 250-500 byte. Will it be confirmed eventually or will mempool reject it ?
I read that happens already after 72h ?
Should I double-spent to cancel it ?

Also, why is it so large ? Could it have been avoided using a new RX address.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: How do you mean "it showed up in the blockchain"? If it's not confirmed, then by definition it is not in the blockchain. Perhaps you mean it's showing up on the blockchain.info website?

Comment: Okcoin must have gotten the help of some miner to confirm it, because it was actually included inspite of it's minuscule fee.

Comment: idk why this appeared on the homepage today but anyways the reason that it's so big is that new transactions are based on previous transactions, and must list all transactions which they get their coins from. In this situation, it looks like you were paid in lots of little bits split in many transactions. So, it has to list all those tiny txs...which adds up to a large tx size.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a rule to spend 20 satoshi per byte you should spend 651380 Satoshi which is 4 times more than you provided in the transaction. It could be likely that you won't get confirmed by a miner, you could make a new transaction and put it through of course.

Both won't go through that's for sure.

Comment: thanks, but how could I have know that the size will be that big ? Now, how can a make a new transaction ? I sent it from okcoin, not my wallet-client which allows RBF.

Comment: If you have access to the private key then you can manually form the transaction (if you have enough experience to do that) I think okcoin would then need to improve their wallet service to recommend an appropriate fee. Eventually a miner will pick it up, or simply drop your transaction.. more likely pick it up.

Comment: i am a quick learner, but have never done it. Any tuts to do that ? How do I obtain the private key ? I am sending from one exchange to another.

Comment: Since you are sending from an exchange it is likely you do not have the private key. Making a transaction manually would require you to manipulate software, or use software appropriately a common mistake is not returning yourself your change. It could cause you to lose all your money if done incorrectly.

Comment: ok, so no really an option. what do you suggest? sitting it out, because it will be eventually confirmed or sent back, or getting in touch with xchange? and anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: I would definitely let the exchange know about the transaction, and see what they will want to do; because after all they are in possession of the private key and should be able to keep you happy!.